# How to stop creating product as virtual in magento 2 programatically?

Tags: magento2.3, catalog, virtual-products, product-type

Some time we forgot to add weight to the product and its become an automatically of type virtual product.

I am trying to generate a product of a type "simple" in case we forgot to add weight ...

I would like to by-pass a condition where product type is set as "virtual".

I have done following workaround for this:

> in the file :
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/TypeTransitionManager.php

under function `processProduct()` i have tried by commenting following line:

```
$product->setTypeId($productTypeId);
```

But it is not working.. How can we handle this programmatically?

Comment: For config child product?

Comment: Yes How can we by-pass the condition o poduct type... and always create the product of type simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwrite following class:

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper/Plugin/Configurable.php

then modify **getVariationMatrix** method.

```
/**
 * Get variation-matrix from request
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getVariationMatrix()
{
    $result = [];
    $configurableMatrix = $this->request->getParam('configurable-matrix-serialized', "[]");
    if (isset($configurableMatrix) && $configurableMatrix != "") {
        $configurableMatrix = json_decode($configurableMatrix, true);

        foreach ($configurableMatrix as $item) {
            if (isset($item['newProduct']) && $item['newProduct']) {
                $result[$item['variationKey']] = $this->mapData($item);

                if (isset($item['qty'])) {
                    $result[$item['variationKey']]['quantity_and_stock_status']['qty'] = $item['qty'];
                }

                $result[$item['variationKey']]['product_has_weight'] = 1;
                $result[$item['variationKey']]['weight'] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Actually, you need to pass following params:

```
$result[$item['variationKey']]['product_has_weight'] = 1;
$result[$item['variationKey']]['weight'] = 1;
```

Comment: This approch is working for me... but I'll test some scenarios and will get back to you... Thanks for the quick reply..

Comment: Yes this is working in both case... when you add individual product... and add associates products. in both case it works well.. Thanks Rana... Actually when you add the associates products as swatch ... these associates products also becomes virtual products.. so this scenario also works..

Comment: Hi sohel, you are assigning the weight as 1 ... isn't it affected to shipping... means we are assigning the weight as 1... so a product which does not have weight will automatically assign weight as 1

Comment: just want to know whether it will affect during shipping or not

Comment: @rohan.katkar no, this function will use only for admin

Comment: So, i can use your code to make the product of type simple without assigning a weight to the product at frontend... and it won't affect during shipping... just clarifying my doubt .. as I am new to magento...

Comment: Weight is important for shipping, you definitely assign some weight for simple product

Comment: ok.. so as per your opinion this function will use only for admin... I'll re-apply the code and check by placing order whether it shoes any information related to weight or not... and will let you know